# F test with inverted hypotheses

Tags: hypothesis-testing, variance, f-test

When using the F test to see whether pooled variance is appropriate, would it not be more useful to assume that the population variances are not equal and let the alternative hypothesis be that they are? The higher the confidence level, the more likely you are to assume that the variances are equal, and this can be rather confusing at first glance.

I figured this would be the right way to do this test (H0: unequal population variances):

Say we use a significance level of 0.05 and we always put the larger sample variance in the numerator of the F ratio. First, we find the cumulative probability at F=1. We do the same for our calculated F statistic. Then we subtract the CDF for F=1 from the CDF for our F statistic, and this gives us the p-value. I figure that we still have to divide the alpha by 2 since it seems to still be a 2-sided test. So, if our p-value is less than alpha/2, we reject the null hypothesis and accept that the population variances are equal. Otherwise, we continue to assume that they are different.

Would this approach be correct? Is there a reason I've struggled to find any literature on such an approach? I've come across a rule of thumb that an F ratio of less than 3 (with numerator always larger) means we can assume equality of population variances. That seems awfully high, corresponding to a high p-value in the inverted test I just described. Is my approach too stringent? I also still don't quite grasp why we have to divide alpha by 2 when using the F test since we are always putting the larger sample variance in the numerator.

Comment: "TOST" is a good search keyword.